Why is Linux broken up by distribution in the survey but Windows is not?
I feel like it's a disservice to the Linux community that we have to add up all of the Linux distribution scores to point out that developers are largely using Linux more than either Windows or macOS.
To be fair, you should break up Windows distributions being used as well or combine Linux just like you've combined all the Windows distributions. Those are Home, Pro, Enterprise, Education, Pro Education, Pro for Workstation as well as all the various server distributions and Windows 10 versus Windows 11. It's not uncommon to run Windows Server distribution on a workstation and I have done it myself in the past.

Those aren't distributions, they're licences. Home can be changed to pro by just changing the license key. You can't take a Ubuntu Install and "make it SUSE" by changing the key. As for 10 Vs 11 that's a version. If you want Windows 10 and 11 then I assume we should list Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, 16.10, 17.04, 17.10, 18.04 LTS, ... 24.10... Distributions aren't a Windows "thing".

which survey are you referring to? does it have a name?

It's not much of a disservice if all one has to do to reach your conclusion is add the numbers.

But you can't just add up the numbers.  I use Debian at work and Ubuntu under WSL at home.  I don't remember how I filled out those boxes, but it's entirely possible I checked all three.  You'd be counting me 2-3 times, depending on whether you include WSL users (yes, it's broken down by personal vs. professional use, but that still only works if Linux users use exactly one distribution for each).

@PresidentJamesK.Polk it tends to obscure the reality of how much market share Linux has here.

@starball note the description of the [survey] tag - it's the Stack Overflow Developer Survey.  At least. the 2024 survey has this issue; it's possible others do as well, but I did not check.

So if for the next survey they add a bar that tallies all the Linuxes, then everyone is happy. Then you have the graph to show who has the biggest one which is the only thing it is going to be good for. I rather like seeing the more popular distributions specifically named, it shows me what other people are gravitating towards which makes me interested to find out what's so special about it. Linux is "special" in that it really is interesting to know the distribution. I couldn't care less about Windows or MacOS versions, it's all the same.

@ThomA the definition of a distribution is that it will have different features. Each distribution of windows that I listed has different features. That’s what makes it a distribution.

@Gimby yes, that would be the fair and correct way to do it.

@starball seems like everybody knew which survey I was talking about, but yeah - the developer survey.

@RyanM they absolutely should be added up. If you use Linux and windows, that’s fine. Each of your percentages will go into the appropriate OS. Since you would be adding to both of them, then the proportion will not be affected. (It’s not percentage of developers that they are counting, it’s simply the proportion of usage)

@WayneBloss not exactly, what happens when someone uses multiple Linux distributions? Although if one wants to make the comparison you want to you can just download (it's publically available) the survey results and calculate those numbers yourself.

@WayneBloss "they absolutely should be added up" No, you're misunderstanding my point.  Consider if I have a group of five people, and one of those people uses Arch, Ubuntu, Fedora, Red Hat, and another Linux distro (that's one person using all five distros, not one using each); the other four use Windows.  The percentages are as follows: Arch (20%), Ubuntu (20%), Fedora (20%), Red Hat (20%), Other Linux (20%), Windows: 80%.  You cannot add those five 20%s up and conclude that 100% of the group uses Linux, because they don't; the correct number is 20%, because all five were the same person.

@RyanM No, you misunderstood my point. "What percentage of developers use Linux" is more useful than "How many developers use ONLY Linux" which is what you seem to be hyper fixating on. Nobody cares about that.

@WayneBloss No, I just gave a simple example to simplify the numbers. Consider a similar scenario of five people.
One person uses Windows, Arch, Ubuntu, Fedora, Red Hat, and another Linux distro (that's one person using all six, not one using each); one uses Windows and Ubuntu; the other three use Windows only. The percentages are: Arch (20%), Ubuntu (40%), Fedora (20%), Red Hat (20%), Other Linux (20%), Windows (100%). You cannot add those five Linux percentages up and conclude that 120% of the group uses Linux; the correct number is 40%, because only two people used Linux.

@WayneBloss In this revised scenario, note specifically that the number I'm fixating on is 40%, despite there being no one who uses ONLY Linux.  Also note that your methodology results in the clearly nonsense result that 120% of the group uses Linux, a result that is obviously incorrect without knowing anything about the group, because it is impossible for more than 100% of a group of people to do something.  Also note that in my original hypothetical (to which you replied), the number of developers who use Linux (one) is the same as the number who use only Linux (also one).

Based on the way you describe your expectations of Windows, and that different versions and licence models needs to be listed independently, this also would mean that the same would need to apply for Linux, Mac, FreeBSD, etc.; this would explode the number of operating systems listed.
Let's take just the latest 2 major Windows versions, 10 and 11. You would minimally need :

Windows 10 Home
Windows 10 Pro
Windows 10 Enterprise
Windows 11 Home
Windows 11 Pro
Windows 11 Enterprise

Based on that you state a "distribution" is defined by different features, then this also means minor versions should also be used. Windows 11 23H2 has many features that say 21H2 didn't. This means that for Windows 11 alone you need to list 4 additional rows (due to the 4 minor versions) per licence model.
Obviously, if we're going to use that treatment, we need to apply it to Linux too. If we take Ubuntu, this has a major release twice a year, with an LTS every 2 years. So we would want (for example) 22.04 LTS, 22.10, 23.04, 23.10, 24.04 LTS and 24.10 listed. Do we also then also need things like 22.04.2 listed as well?
What about users that have a licence for Ubuntu Pro? Do we then need to list that separately again, for each version, like we are for Home and Pro on Windows? I assume so.
What about ARM Vs AMD64? From a  feature side these are vastly different, so surely yes; that explodes the amount again.
Honestly, this sounds like a terrible UX for all involved.

Instead I would suggest that there is a separate question, explicitly for what type of operating systems you use, which can list Windows, Linux, Mac, FreeBSD, etc. Hopefully, if any of those are ticked, then further questions for version or distro could be prompted.
So if I ticked Windows, ChromeOS, and Linux, I could then select 11 and 10 for Windows, and (K)Ubuntu, Debian, and Arch for Linux; this would be 3 separate questions. ChromeOS could also have an option for actual ChromeOS and ChromeOS Flex.
If Stack Overflow chose, they could also have questions about architecture, such as AMD64, Intel86, ARM, RISC, etc.
This is, of course, too late now but for future surveys this seems like a better™ solution, and doesn't explode the options as proposed here.

To illustrate a point, Thorm forgot the numerous different editions of Windows IoT, Windows on ARM, and Windows Home Single Language.  So, at least 6 more options would have to be added, for just Windows 10 and Windows 11 and you don't even get into Windows Server.

Thom @SecurityHound ...

Dirty monitor...lol

I'm not sure "Thorm" is any better. :(

Did I mention my display (or my glasses) are really dirty?

Yeah it does sound terrible because that was the less preferable and frankly terrible alternative that I outlined. The better and quite obviously, more fair, alternative is to show a total for all Linux vs all Windows and macOS.
